# How can the thrust due to radiation pressure be amplified in photonic laser thruster?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, laser

The thrust is amplified due to repeated bouncing of photons between two mirrors as shown in the diagram in [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/Photon-Thrust-Amplification.jpg): [image] Why does repeated bouncing of photons produce amplified thrust when the answer in '[Mirror problem of radiation pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57766/)' indicates that the radiation pressure will only be doubled?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is misleading. If you consider one photon it is giving each mirror a kick every T seconds. There is no "continuous pressure". Now multiply that by N photons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "multiple photons" and "repeated photons". If one photon keeps bouncing back and forth, it can carry a little bit of impulse from one mirror to the other on each round trip. When you have multiple photons, each of them can do this. So your "amplification" comest from either

- Waiting a long time, so the photon makes lots of round trips
- Adding lots of photons.

In either case, the total impulse imparted scales with number of (photon-round trips).